# Groovy lanaguge - How to destroy/switch to an application

Tags: groovy

I'm using the groovy language in robotic application (RPA Express). I can not figure out how to do two things in the groovy language.

I start an application with these command:

```
def proc = new ProcessBuilder( args )
Process process = proc.start()
```

My questions are:

1. How do I close this application? (I want to close the application at the end of the script)?
2. How do I switch to this application window? (I want to be sure the application window is always focused)?

Answer (score 0):

Both depend on the OS.

1. <strike>You need to invoke a kill task command to kill the process by its pid (e.g. `kill` on Linux)</strike>. As Joachim mentions in the comments, `Process` has `destroy()` and `destroyForcibly()`.
2. You need to use the window manager API to focus the window of the given pid you want.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using window 10. How do I get the pid?

Comment: [`Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html) has `pid()`, `destroy()` and `destroyForcibly()` methods.

Comment: @JoachimSauer True, I was looking at [Groovy's Process](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.7.2/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html).

Comment: @m0skit0: yeah, it's unfortunately that the GroovyDoc really only shows *additional* methods over what the JDK already provides.

Comment: Thanks but it does not work. I tried. process.destroyForcibly(); but is does not close the application. When I tried the process.pid() the groovy script ends.

Comment: Are you waiting in your script for the process? Otherwise the Groovy script will just end after spawning the new process.